How to call javaScript from Controler on Firefox?
I'm trying to call JavaScript from bean. Script it work correct but when try to run it from bean get a error: Uncaught ReferenceError: funkcjaKolorujPredkosc is not defined
It is import to xml:
 <h:head>          
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.0.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"></script>    

        <script src="JavaScript/KolorSpeed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </h:head> 

Script looks like that:
$(document).ready(
        
    function funkcjaKolorujPredkosc(){
        
        var allCells = $(".kolorSpeed > div");

        $.each(allCells, function (index, child) {

            var speedString = (child.textContent.replace("/","-")).toString();

            var index = speedString.indexOf("-");

            var actualSpeed = parseInt(speedString.substring(0, index)); 

            var targetSpeed = parseInt(speedString.substring(index+1, speedString.length));        

            if (actualSpeed >= targetSpeed){
                $(child).parent().css("color", "green");}
            else{
                $(child).parent().css("color", "red");
            }
        }); 
    }
);

Calling from Bean:
public void idleMonitro() throws IOException, ParseException{
dataUpdate();        
PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("funkcjaKolorujPredkosc();");

}
On Microsoft Edge it is working correct, there is a problem only on Firefox.

function funkcjaKolorujPredkosc() {};
    
    $(document).ready(
            
        function funkcjaKolorujPredkosc(){
    

all things the same, because you must pre-declared mechanism, definition without body structure

Did not help, the same error on Firefox (jQuery.Deferred exception: funkcjaKolorujPredkosc is not defined @http://localhost:8090/MesDashboard/:3246:52)

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function funkcjaKolorujPredkosc() {
var allCells = $(".kolorSpeed > div");
    $.each(

});     zamiast $(document).ready https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery
